# Combobox and deleted record

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have 2 related tables - CarMarks and CarMarkGroups. Any CarMark has CarMarkGroupID. I have edit form for CarMarks with combobox binding to CarMarkGroups.
[image]

I mark one of CarMarkGroup as deleted record. So, this marked CarMarkGroup is not in list binding to combobox (because I must show only active CarMarkGroups). But CarMarkGroupID in selected CarMark still links to marked as deleted CarMarkGroup. And i dont need to change this link.
[image]

But I need show this record for selected CarMark even if it was marked for deletion. What is the best practice for that? Need I build list for combobox in ChangeSelection Event? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd propose a solution, based on [`ICollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) filtering.
View models:

```
public class GroupViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel(List<GroupViewModel> groups)
    {
        Groups = new ListCollectionView(groups)
        {
            Filter = g =>
            {
                var group = (GroupViewModel)g;

                return !group.IsDeleted || (Group == group);
            }
        };
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public GroupViewModel Group
    {
        get { return group; }
        set
        {
            if (group != value)
            {
                group = value;
                Groups.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
    private GroupViewModel group;

    public ICollectionView Groups { get; private set; }
}

public class ListViewModel
{
    private readonly List<GroupViewModel> groups;

    public ListViewModel()
    {
        // some sample initialization
        groups = new List<GroupViewModel>
        {
            new GroupViewModel { Name = "Friuts" },
            new GroupViewModel { Name = "Animals" },
            new GroupViewModel { Name = "Trees", IsDeleted = true }
        };

        Items = new List<ItemViewModel>
        {
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Orange", Group = groups[0] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Apple", Group = groups[0] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Banana", Group = groups[0] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Cat", Group = groups[1] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Dog", Group = groups[1] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Bird", Group = groups[1] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Oak", Group = groups[2] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Nut-tree", Group = groups[2] },
            new ItemViewModel(groups) { Name = "Pine", Group = groups[2] },
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

View (it's a `Window` content in WPF Application project):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="ItemsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Binding="{Binding Group.Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ItemsGrid}">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" SelectedItem="{Binding Group}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ListViewModel();
    }
}
```

So, when item is selected, `ComboBox` contains all non-deleted groups PLUS group of selected item, if this group is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand the connections exactly but if you still need to see that CarMarkGroup in your CarMarks ComboBox, maybe add a boolean flag in your CarMarkGroup, something like ProposedForDeletion and when that changes to true, you change some color or another element in the GUI to let the user now it was proposed for deletion, or even display a message regarding this somewhere. Do not delete it from the ObservableCollection but just mark its flag to true and keep it there and do your further check according to this new flag.

Comment: You understand me. And I really dont delete CarAMrkGroup. I mark record for deleting by set field IsDeleted. I can show "deleted" CarMarkGroups in my combobox and color them in red e.g. But I dont need it. Because there are many "deleted" Groups. And users dont need see them all. Ideally, I want to show only actual Groups and one "deleted" Group if it's linked to selected CarMark.

Comment: @AndrewK So, if you select a CarMark which has a link to a deleted CarmMarkGroup you want to display that CarMarkGroup somewhere. OK, so add another flag IsSelected, which will be bounded to the SelectedItem of the CarMark row. If you update your post with some code maybe we can figure out the bindings for this. Maybe we are talking about a MultiBinding here, taking into consideration you need to check two flags to update the GUI. If deleted don't show it, but if deleted and selected, display it.

Comment: My question is not about realization. It's about principle of decision for this problem. I write on c# but this problem is actually for Delphi or some other too. In my last projects I do it simple: I do not allow to delete Group if any CarMark links to it. And before now it works.

Comment: in generally, how I must show linked CarMarkGroup even if it was marked for deletion, and dont show al other "deleted" Groups. Maybe not in combobox? Maybe texbox with button, and popup-control with DataGrid of Groups?

Comment: I would add all the Groups in a DataGrid, and a ToolTip on would appear when hovering over on deleted or proposed for deletion ones containing the status,meaning this group was deleted or, it's in progress of deletion. If the user can change from the GUI to take some actions regarding this, you can place that button you are talking about too..